# How to index DateTime in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a few columns where some values are DateTime and some are simply the year. I'd like to index the values of the datetime such that if `I = I[:4]` I get the year for variable I after looping through the column instead of an error stating `'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable`. Essentially, I'd like to drop everything from datetime that isn't the year in a column with mixed ints that have values that are only the year, and datetime instances from which I would only like to retrieve the year.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do and unfortunately I cannot post comments (yet).

From what I guess, you have a DataFrame with a column of mixed types, and you want to convert all values with type `datetime` to `int`. As an example, here is a DataFrame:

```
    >>> data = [[1, 1990], [2, datetime(1991, 1, 1)]]
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'time'])
    >>> df
       id                 time
    0   1                 1990
    1   2  1991-01-01 00:00:00
```

You can use `map`([link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)) to convert the second column:

```
    >>> df.loc[:,'date'] = df.loc[:,'date'].map(lambda x: x.year if isinstance(x, datetime) else x)
    >>> df
       id  time
    0   1  1990
    1   2  1991
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.